# I get Failed to compile error in React Redux app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I get following error in chrome dev tool:
Failed to compile.
C:/Users/marci/OneDrive/Pulpit/moja_apka/blog/src/index.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-redux' in 'C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\moja_apka\blog\src'

Below are my dependencies from package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.0",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
"@types/react": "^17.0.9",
"@types/react-dom": "^17.0.6",
"@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
"@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
"@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
"expo": "^41.0.1",
"expo-cli": "^4.5.2",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-icons": "^4.2.0",
"react-router": "^5.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"react-transition-group": "^4.4.2",
"styled-components": "^5.3.0",
"type-redux": "^2.0.2",
"typescript": "^4.3.2",
"web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
```

and index.tsx file :

```
  import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { App } from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store/store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: It's in the package.json but is it installed? `npm install` or `npm list react-redux` to verify?

Comment: actually, it looks like only the types are in package.json, not the library itself. Do `npm install react-redux`